# What do the markings 40/100/56/B mean on this capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

I am trying to replace a steam iron capacitor which has the following markings
[image]

I know that it's 0.68 micro Farad with 10% tolerance, but I can't seem to understand the 40/100/56 marking. There's replacements online with 40/100/21 so I'd like to know if they're suitable.

Thank you.

Comment: It looks like it's a climatic category https://forum.digikey.com/t/climatic-category-on-film-capacitors/2952

Comment: That is an X2 rated safety capacitor. Unless you can safely determine an alternative X2 rated safety capacitor, let a person with qualifications for working with and fixing mains voltage circuits fix it.

Other than that, I have no idea what the markings mean. You need to determine that from capacitor manufacturer data sheets. Chanses are they are simply a date or traceability code.

Comment: What makes you think the capacitor is bad?  Keep in mind that resistance measurements on a PCB are often incorrect.

Comment: When taken out of the PCB it measures 0.35 uF instead of anywhere in the 0.68 +- 10% tolerance. There is a problem with faulty steaming in this iron as I also saw in the article https://lieven.kks36.be/2016/06/11/philips-perfectcare-aqua-does-not-pump-solved/ and I have the same problem - the capacitance on my one has also gone down and I'm hoping replacing the capacitor will fix the issue.

Comment: (It's 110, not 100.)

Comment: sorry, yes, 110, I saw a 40/100 one online and assumed this was the same without double checking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is the [climatic category](https://forum.digikey.com/t/climatic-category-on-film-capacitors/2952) data for your capacitor.

Your capacitor is rated from -40 to +110 degrees C.  The 56 means that your capacitor will be OK if operated at 95% humidity and 40 degrees C for 56 days.

The "B" might be the flammability rating, as described in [this document from Vishay (see page 5.)](https://www.vishay.com/docs/26033/gentechinfofilm.pdf)

Given that you mention a steam iron, I think you'd be better off finding capacitors with the same climatic rating as the original.

---

That capacitor is a safety capacitor - that's the "X2" marking.

Make sure that any replacement is also rated X2 and also has the same voltage rating as the original.

Comment: Thank you for the info - I looked up the data sheet and saw it mentioned -40 to +100 degrees Celsius but no mention of the 56. For safety I'll definitely get the same or higher voltage capacitor, and a 56 rated one if I can do, but it seems 21 ratings are more abundant from where I'm looking so I might have to get that one. I believe this shouldn't be an issue as it cools down between uses so it never gets past 1 day at the temperature, let alone 56 days...

Comment: The test is may be 56 days in one chunk.  The effect itself might be cumulative - total of time spent at 95% humidity and 40 degrees.  Worst case, the capacitor quits again earlier than a 56 day rated part.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting, didn't know that it could have cumulative effects. I'll likely look for a 56 rated one in that case and maybe multiple in case it breaks again, I'll have a spare. Thank you

Comment: I don't know  that it does have cumulative effects.  It **might.**  There's probably more information in the standard (IEC 60068-1) mentioned in both links.  I don't have access to a copy of the standard, though.